# C++ Macro - process two pairs of parentheses

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I need to preprocess this code:

```
line (0,0) (5,5)
```

where the (0,0) means start x and y coordinate and the second (5,5) means end x and y coordinates.

I was able to fetch the start coordinates using

```
#define line(x1,y1)   myArray->shapes.push_back(new Line(x1,y1));
```

How can I process the second parentheses?

Comment: Perhaps `#define line(x1, y1) myArray->...; line2` and `#define line2(x2, y2) myArray->...;` but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Why use preprocessing? If the answer by @OmnipotentEntity is what you want, why not implement a `void line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)` function?

Comment: I want to implement my own DSL language and this is how I designed it. I hope it will be implementable though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about something like the following:

```
struct LineCreator {
  LineCreator(type_of_shapes &shapes, int x1, int y1)
    : shapes_(shapes), x1_(x1), y1_(y1)
  {}
  void operator() (int x2, int y2) {
    shapes_.push_back(new Line(x1_, y1_, x2, y2));
  }
private:
  type_of_shapes &shapes_;
  int x1_, y1_;
};

#define line(x, y) LineCreator(myArray->shapes, (x), (y))
```

Comment: Ooooooh, that's interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
line (0,0,5,5)
```

And now you can construct the following macro:

```
#define line(x1,y1,x2,y2)   myArray->shapes.push_back(new Line(x1,y1)); \
                            myArray->shapes.push_back(new Line(x2,y2));
```

Comment: I was hoping I could preprocess two pairs of parentheses - I guess that isn't possible?